# Revelation 20:12: "Books were opened"

Tags: revelation

Rev 20:12 says:

> And I saw the dead, the great and the small, standing before the
>   throne, and books were opened; and another book was opened, which is
>   the book of life; and the dead were judged from the things which were
>   written in the books, according to their deeds.

I wonder about the meaning of "Another book was opened", could it be that the "books" will be new books of the Bible that have information that today we simply would not be able to understand?
Or maybe the word "books" mean: situations (bad or good) that may happen in the future?

Comment: What are you asking?  Can you tell us where this "a new rolls will open" comes from?

Comment: Revelation 20:12

Comment: Pls edit your post and quote the specific verse that you find troubling, so that moderators can cast their votes to reopen your question. As it is now it is still not acceptable.

Comment: The dead were judged from the contents of the books. Thus, the books appear to be  a record of what occurred in time, before time ended. Then, also, there is the book of life.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Revelation 20:12: “Books were opened”**

To the Israelites God gave them directions under the "law of Moses " and to the Christians the "law of  Christ". (Galatians 6:2) Now the Bible tells us that books will be opened , we read:

Revelation 20:12  (NASB)

> 12 "And I saw the dead, the great and the small, standing before the
>   throne, and books were opened; and another book was opened, which is
>   the book of life; and the dead were judged from the things which were
>   written in the books, according to their deeds."

Since Romans 6:7 says :

**"For he who has died is freed from sin."** that is acquitted from their
 sins prior to their death ,so  those resurrected will not be judged on
 deeds, in their former life ,but on the things/deeds which are written
 in the books after being resurrected.

Obviously the books will contain God's new  laws and commandments for mankind and  which all people , including those resurrected will be able to study and get to know God's will for them.  Like you said It could be new books added to the Bible or New Books , with entirely new requirements for mankind.

The books will certainly  give us new insight into God's mind ,for example  the prophecy of Isaiah 61:11 tells us that in the new world, righteousness will prevail. **"For as the earth brings forth its sprouts, and as a garden causes the things sown in it to spring up, so the Lord God will cause righteousness and praise to spring up before all the nations."(NASB)**

Answer (score 0):

Peace.

The great white throne signifies the Day of Judgment when the Lord opens up the “books” of the Bible to our understanding.  It is His words…His interpretation of the words of the biblical saints (the many witnesses)…that we are to hear and receive in belief and to worship God in the hearing of His Truth.

The “dead”….the “dead in trespasses and sins” here in this earth…shall hear His voice as He opens  up the Scriptures (the “books” are opened) to our hearing ears.  This is not about the “afterlife” but about the time of Judgment at the conclusion of this age for those who are on this earth.

The Son of God comes to give us an understanding by the opening up of the books of the Bible to our understanding and we are to be found of Him worshipping God….showing that we know Him who is true.  Whosoever is born of God does not sin…does not speak evil against what they hear in their unbelief and wrath.

> 1 John 5:18-20 KJV (18)  ***We know that whosoever is born of God sinneth
>   not; but he that is begotten of God keepeth himself, and that wicked
>   one toucheth him not.*** (19)  And we know that we are of God, and the
>   whole world lieth in wickedness.

We show we know Him by the hearing of the true and faithful words of God (as interpreted by Christ by the opening up to the understanding of the Scriptures) and receiving them with good works towards what we hear.

> (20)  ***And we know that the Son of God is come, and hath given us an
>   understanding, that we may know him that is true,*** and we are in him
>   that is true, even in his Son Jesus Christ. This is the true God, and
>   eternal life.

Some will hear and believe what He says and will be found worshipping/praising God in thanksgiving while others will hear and not believe and will be found speaking evil in contentions and wrath...strife and envy.

The earth and heaven shall pass away but His words shall not.  We have His full attention during this time of judgment as the “face the earth and the heaven fled away; and there was found no place for them.”  His focus then will be on us and our responses to His Word of Truth.

> Revelation 20: KJV (11)  *And I saw a great white throne, and him that
>   sat on it, **from whose face the earth and the heaven fled away**; and
>   there was found no place for them.*

By our own words shall we be judged as every idle word said during the Day of Judgment will we be held accountable.   Some will do good towards the hearing of His words.  They will manifest their faith with good works.

The “dead’ are judged out of those things which are written in the books of the Bible….that is, they are judged on how they receive the interpretations of the Writings/Scriptures according to the mind of Christ who interprets them.

> (12)  *And I saw the dead, small and great, stand before God; **and the
>   books were opened: and another book was opened, which is the book of
>   life: and the dead were judged out of those things which were written
>   in the books, according to their works.** (13)  And the sea gave up the
>   dead which were in it; and death and hell delivered up the dead which
>   were in them: and they were judged every man according to their works.*

A good man will hear and  bring forth good things out of the heart and mouth while an evil man will bring forth evil things towards what he will hear:  the hearing of the interpretation of Christ who opens up the Writings/Scriptures (the books) to our ears in the Day of Judgment.  The Writings are interpreted in the Spirit of Truth….the 7 Spirits of God…the full knowledge of the Word of Truth.

An evil man....like a raging sea...will not hear and have peace but will be found "raging" against what he hears.  the sea will give up the dead in it.

> Matthew 12:35-37 KJV (35)  ***A good man out of the good treasure of the
>   heart bringeth forth good things: and an evil man out of the evil
>   treasure bringeth forth evil things.*** (36)  But I say unto you, That
>   every idle word that men shall speak, they shall give account thereof
>   in the day of judgment. (37)  For by thy words thou shalt be
>   justified, and by thy words thou shalt be condemned.

He that hears His word AND believes on Him that sent Him to interpret these things has everlasting life (being found written in the book of life).  They will not come into the Judgment but will have passed from death unto life.

> John 5:24-30 KJV (24)  *Verily, verily, I say unto you, **He that heareth
>   my word, and believeth on him that sent me, hath everlasting life, and
>   shall not come into condemnation; but is passed from death unto life.**
>   (25)  Verily, verily, I say unto you, The hour is coming, and now is,
>   when the dead shall hear the voice of the Son of God: and they that
>   hear shall live. (26)  For as the Father hath life in himself; so hath
>   he given to the Son to have life in himself; (27)  And hath given him
>   authority to execute judgment also, because he is the Son of man.*

They shall do good when they hear His interpretation of the Scriptures (the “books” are opened) as they will believe in what they hear and will be found doing good and will be found in the book of life as they stand up unto life while those who will do evil will hear and speak “idle” words unto judgment.

> (28)  *Marvel not at this: for the hour is coming, in the which all
>   that are in the graves shall hear his voice, (29)  **And shall come
>   forth; they that have done good, unto the resurrection of life; and
>   they that have done evil, unto the resurrection of damnation**.*

As He hears, He judges as by our own words on how we respond to the hearing of the books of the Bible being opened up shall we be judged.

> (30)  *I can of mine own self do nothing: **as I hear, I judge: and my
>   judgment is just**; because I seek not mine own will, but the will of
>   the Father which hath sent me.*

We are to be found responding to what we hear the Spirit saying by letting God be true (with His Word) and every man a liar (as we have all previously heard the private interpretations of the books of the Bible by man’s misunderstanding  and deceptive handling of them).   We are to be justified by our sayings.

> Romans 3:4 KJV (4)  *God forbid: yea, **let God be true, but every man a
>   liar; as it is written, That thou mightest be justified in thy
>   sayings, and mightest overcome when thou art judged**.*

We are justified in our sayings towards what we will hear:  the opening up of the books of the Bible to our understanding.  Some will continue to not be righteous….while others will be righteous.

We “seal” that God is true when we hear His voice opening up the books of the Bible to our understanding in the testimony of Jesus.  We attest to the true and faithful words of God when we hear them in the testimony of Jesus who opens up the books to our hearing ears.   We are then found in the Book of Life….crossing over from death to life.

> John 3:31-34 KJV (31)  *He that cometh from above is above all: he that
>   is of the earth is earthly, and speaketh of the earth: he that cometh
>   from heaven is above all. (32)  **And what he hath seen and heard, that
>   he testifieth; and no man receiveth his testimony. (33)  He that hath
>   received his testimony hath set to his seal that God is true**.*

God sends His Son to give us an understanding as He is sent to speak the words of God….the true and faithful Witness who speaks the full true and faithful words of God to our hearing ears. Those who will hear in belief will be given the full knowledge of God.

> (34)  ***For he whom God hath sent speaketh the words of God:*** for God
>   giveth not the Spirit by measure unto him.

He is the “faithful and true Witness” who speaks the true and faithful words of God in the correct interpretation of the Scriptures.  Man’s earthly witness has been wrong while His is true and we are to respond with good works.

> Revelation 3:14-15 KJV (14)  *And unto the angel of the church of the
>   Laodiceans write; These things saith the Amen, **the faithful and true
>   witness,** the beginning of the creation of God; (15)  I know thy works,
>   that thou art neither cold nor hot: I would thou wert cold or hot.*

When we receive His words in faith in this coming time as the “true and faithful” words of God, then we are found written in the book of life.    “Write: for these words are true and faithful.”

Our names are found written in the Book of Life when we receive the testimony of Jesus :  the true and faithful words of God that He speaks.  We seal that His testimony is true....they are of God.

"It is done" as our names are found written in the Book of Life as we attest that His words are “true and faithful” while man’s interpretations of the Bible are not. We are found believing on Him and His testimony.   Let God be true and every man a liar.

> Revelation 21:5-8 KJV (5)  *And he that sat upon the throne said,
>   Behold, I make all things new. And he said unto me, **Write: for these
>   words are true and faithful.** (6)  And he said unto me, It is done. I
>   am Alpha and Omega, the beginning and the end. I will give unto him
>   that is athirst of the fountain of the water of life freely. (7)  He
>   that overcometh shall inherit all things; and I will be his God, and
>   he shall be my son.*

His sayings are the “faithful and true” words of God.  Happy are those who keep the “sayings” (the worship and praise of God) of the prophecy of this book.  They hear His testimony and worship God.

> Revelation 22:6-7 KJV (6)  *And he said unto me, These sayings are
>   faithful and true: and the Lord God of the holy prophets sent his
>   angel to shew unto his servants the things which must shortly be done.
>   (7)  Behold, I come quickly: blessed is he that keepeth the sayings of
>   the prophecy of this book.*

Seal not the “sayings” of the prophecy of this book.   What will the work be of every person towards what he or she hears? How shall people respond in their words to the hearing of His interpretations?

> Revelation 22:10-12 KJV (10)  *And he saith unto me, **Seal not the
>   sayings of the prophecy of this book: for the time is at hand.** (11) 
>   He that is unjust, let him be unjust still: and he which is filthy,
>   let him be filthy still: and he that is righteous, let him be
>   righteous still: and he that is holy, let him be holy still. (12) 
>   **And, behold, I come quickly; and my reward is with me, to give every
>   man according as his work shall be.***

Seal not the sayings.  What are the “sayings”?

They are the sayings of the worshipping of God ….praising Him in thanksgiving of what we hear when He opens up the Scriptures (the “books”) to our hearing ears in the Spirit of Truth.  These are sayings that we are not to “seal”…not to stop up…not to keep quiet.

Seal not the sayings but instead openly praise Him:  “Salvation to our God which sitteth upon the throne, and unto the Lamb.”

> Revelation 7:10-13 KJV (10)  *And cried with a loud voice, **saying,
>   Salvation to our God which sitteth upon the throne, and unto the Lamb.**
>   (11)  And all the angels stood round about the throne, and about the
>   elders and the four beasts, and fell before the throne on their faces,
>   **and worshipped God,***

Seal not the sayings:      “Amen: Blessing, and glory, and wisdom, and thanksgiving, and honour, and power, and might, be unto our God for ever and ever. Amen.”

> (12)  ***Saying, Amen: Blessing, and glory, and wisdom, and thanksgiving,
>   and honour, and power, and might, be unto our God for ever and ever.
>   Amen.***

Seal not the sayings:  “Thou art worthy, O Lord, to receive glory and honour and power: for thou hast created all things, and for thy pleasure they are and were created.”

> Revelation 4:9-11 KJV (9)  *And when those beasts give glory and honour
>   and thanks to him that sat on the throne, who liveth for ever and
>   ever, (10)  The four and twenty elders fall down before him that sat
>   on the throne, **and worship him that liveth for ever and ever,** and cast
>   their crowns before the throne, **saying, (11)  Thou art worthy, O Lord,
>   to receive glory and honour and power: for thou hast created all
>   things, and for thy pleasure they are and were created**.*

Seal not the sayings:  “Worthy is the Lamb that was slain to receive power, and riches, and wisdom, and strength, and honour, and glory, and blessing.”

“Blessing, and honour, and glory, and power, be unto him that sitteth upon the throne, and unto the Lamb for ever and ever.”

> Revelation 5:11-13 KJV (11)  *And I beheld, and I heard the voice of
>   many angels round about the throne and the beasts and the elders: and
>   the number of them was ten thousand times ten thousand, and thousands
>   of thousands; (12)  **Saying with a loud voice, Worthy is the Lamb that
>   was slain to receive power, and riches, and wisdom, and strength, and
>   honour, and glory, and blessing.** (13)  And every creature which is in
>   heaven, and on the earth, and under the earth, and such as are in the
>   sea, and all that are in them, **heard I saying, Blessing, and honour,
>   and glory, and power, be unto him that sitteth upon the throne, and
>   unto the Lamb for ever and ever.***

But some will hear the testimony of Jesus as He opens up the books and will add unto these things as they will add their own unrighteousness as they contend with what they hear instead of praising Him. Their sayings will be contentious and evil in unbelief and wrath.

> Romans 2:5-9 KJV (5)  *But after thy hardness and impenitent heart
>   treasurest up unto thyself wrath against the day of wrath and
>   revelation of the righteous judgment of God; (6)  **Who will render to
>   every man according to his deeds:** (7)  To them who by patient
>   continuance in well doing seek for glory and honour and immortality,
>   eternal life: (8)  **But unto them that are contentious, and do not obey
>   the truth, but obey unrighteousness, indignation and wrath,** (9) 
>   Tribulation and anguish, upon every soul of man that doeth evil, of
>   the Jew first, and also of the Gentile;*

Others will disesteem what they hear in their ultimate rejection of His words that are “true and faithful” as they have supposedly better things to do.    They will “take away” from those words as they will shun them for other things of this world.

> Matthew 13:22 KJV (22)  *He also that received seed among the thorns is
>   **he that heareth the word; and the care of this world, and the
>   deceitfulness of riches, choke the word, and he becometh unfrui**tfu*l.

Some will have other things supposed “better to do” as they will shun His testimony….the 
“great supper”…the true and faithful words of God:

“I pray thee have me excused.”

> Luke 14:16-20 KJV (16)  *Then said he unto him, A certain man made a
>   great supper, and bade many: (17)  And sent his servant at supper time
>   to say to them that were bidden, Come; for all things are now ready.
>   (18)  **And they all with one consent began to make excuse.** The first
>   said unto him, I have bought a piece of ground, and I must needs go
>   and see it: **I pray thee have me excused.** (19)  And another said, I
>   have bought five yoke of oxen, and I go to prove them: **I pray thee
>   have me excused.** (20)  And another said, I have married a wife, and
>   **therefore I cannot come.***

None of those who were invited to the "great supper" will be able to enter in to understand the true and faithful words of God spoken in the testimony of Jesus when the “books were opened”.   They are not found in the book of life.

> Luke 14:24 KJV (24)  ***For I say unto you, That none of those men which
>   were bidden shall taste of my supper.***

Whoever is not found written in the Book of life is cast into the lake of fire where the tongue is a fire and will speak evil of what one hears and of those who will receive His words.

There will be no more sacrifice for their willful sins as their judgment is final until they perish from this earth for their sins at the hearing of His voice.

> Revelation 20:14-15 KJV (14)  *And death and hell were cast into the
>   lake of fire. This is the second death. (15)  And whosoever was not
>   found written in the book of life was cast into the lake of fire.*

The same group will not be found responding in good works in the Day of Judgment.  they will not “fear God and give glory to Him….”  They will not be found worshipping God at the hearing of His faithful and true words that they will hear and not believe.

> Revelation 14:6-7 KJV (6)  *And I saw another angel fly in the midst of
>   heaven, having the everlasting gospel to preach unto them that dwell
>   on the earth, and to every nation, and kindred, and tongue, and
>   people, (7)  **Saying with a loud voice, Fear God, and give glory to
>   him; for the hour of his judgment is come: and worship him** that made
>   heaven, and earth, and the sea, and the fountains of waters.*

There will be no more sacrifice for their willful sins.  There will be no remedy…no mercy…in the Day of Judgment.

The unbelievers will hear the true and faithful words of God and will do evil towards them and will come into the judgement of God as they will be tormented in the presence of the “holy angels”….the faithful and true words of God.    They will hear His words (the holy messages/angels of the Lord) and in their unbelief speak evil (and the tongue is a fire which will bring upon themselves torment).

They will also be tormented with fire in the presence of the Lamb….in the presence of those who will keep the Lord’s dying in their mortal bodies as they will die to sin in the presence of their persecutions of those who will receive His words.

> Revelation 14:10 KJV (10)  *The same shall drink of the wine of the
>   wrath of God, which is poured out without mixture into the cup of his
>   indignation; **and he shall be tormented with fire and brimstone in the
>   presence of the holy angels, and in the presence of the Lamb**:*

The people who will keep the commandments of God and the faith of Jesus when they hear His words will be persecuted by the unbelievers who have their part in the “lake of fire”.  But blessed are the “dead” which die in the Lord…those who will keep the dying of the Lord in their mortal bodies as they will die to sin when faced with the evil of those who do not believe.  They will not return evil for their evil but will instead keep the sacrifice of the Lamb in their presence which will torment them.

> Revelation 14:12-13 KJV (12)  *H**ere is the patience of the saints: here
>   are they that keep the commandments of God, and the faith of Jesus.**
>   (13)  And I heard a voice from heaven saying unto me, Write, Blessed
>   are **the dead which die in the Lord** from henceforth: Yea, saith the
>   Spirit, that they may rest from their labours; and their works do
>   follow them.*